# Extracting `<key>:<value>` pairs with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

there is a textarea and want to extract with `key:value` (something like below image)

[image]

I have a regex but not working as expected

```
/([^\s][a-zA-Z!]+:(\s)?"?([a-z0-9\s.]+)"?[^ $])/gi
```

if the user enters the below string at that time regex break the group `key:value`.

`is:"browser" browser: "chrome 11.11 V" node: error type:"Error"`

expected group:

```
is:"browser"
browser: "chrome 11.11 V"
node: error 
type:"Error"
```

Comment: Try `/(\w+)=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))/` - Group 1 will contain the key, Group 2 or Group 3 will contain the value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not working, I've updated the question.

Comment: Replace `=` with `:` and [it will work](https://regex101.com/r/JU8GiU/1).

Comment: See my answer proving it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = 'is:"browser" browser: "chrome 11.11 V" node: error type:"Error"';
const re = /(\w+):\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))/g;
let dict = {}, m;
while(m = re.exec(text)) {
  dict[m[1]]=(m[3] || m[2]);
}
console.log(dict);

// Or just get all matches:
console.log(text.match(re))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JU8GiU/1). *Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))` - either of

  - `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, 0+ non-commas (captured in Group 2), `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)` - Group 3: one or more non-whitespaces chars.

Answer (score -1):

Regex:

```
/([a-zA-Z!]+:\s*[" ]?([a-z0-9\s.]+)[" $])/gi
```

Text:

```
sdfd:"dsffs" dsfd: "dsf demo" sfd: dsf fdsff:"fdsfsdf"
```

List:

```
sdfd:"dsffs"
dsfd: "dsf demo"
sfd: dsf 
fdsff:"fdsfsdf"
```